# Unit testing in VS2010 - "Debug" passes, "Run" fails

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I'm having a strange issue with unit testing in Visual Studio 2010.
I have a test that passes when I use "Debug test" (without any breakpoints), but failes when I use "Run test".
This test uses external dll's, so I can't debug it properly.

Do you know of any reason why a situation like this is possible? 
Why "Debug test" is different than "Run test", when all other parameters are the same?

Comment: Do you have any `CondtionalAttribute` in your code base that only execute for debug? Any `#if Debug` sections? In the third party libraries it is entirely possible that they do things differently in debug vs release modes.

Comment: Adding to Oded's question, is there any specific code that is timing specific? Any part of the code that may need a delay will pass when you are debugging but will fail in normal flow.

Comment: Did you checked the test result window and see what error you are getting there.

Comment: A unit test that doesn't let you diagnose the test failure is not a very good test.  Fix that first, the rest will be easy.

Answer (score 3):

Switch you solution to Release mode instead of Debug, run a full build, switch back to debug and retry and let me know the outcome, I think the tests will pass....

Answer (score 2):

There can be several reasons, but to pin-point one, you'll have to give us some code to work with.

It could be code exclusion:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
//do something
#endif
```

This will only be executed in debug mode.

It could be optimizations. Although they shouldn't normally affect the behavior, you shouldn't rely on destructors or copy constructors being called.

If you're doing any hacking inside the code, it might also only be valid for debug.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suspect that you are accessing memory out of bounds.   One major difference between debug and release is that debug adds kits if padding and special markers to memory allocations to catch certain kinds of errors.  This means the memory layouts are often very different between debug and release builds.  I would suspect that you are accessing memory out of bounds in a way that the debugger isn't catching, where you find an accidentally valid value in the debug version, but an invalid one in the release version.